# Site saves index.php file rather than opening it into localserver WAMP

Tags: php

I have a website on a WAMP server. When I launch the website´s folder, it tries to save the index.php file rather than displaying the generated page in the web browser. What can I do about this?

Comment: Just some questions: In which application are you clicking it's folder in wamp directory? Are you clicking a folder or are you clicking a file? Do you do a single-click or a double-click? Which windows operating system are you using?

Comment: I am clicking its folder in wamp webserver. Windows xp i am using. i use single-click. Other projects are also in wamp server. They are running. But the project i have pasted question for is not working.

Comment: You can not click a folder in wamp webserver. I think you mean you're clicking it in a directory listing given by the HTTP server that is displayed in your webbrowser, right?

Comment: This project running live, but not locally.

Answer (score 7):

It is solved. the  .htaccess file was creating problem, I deleted that file from the folder , now it is working perfect. Thank you all for helping

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no this line: `AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .php` in your httpd.conf (uncommented).

Second possible problem: wrong content of `doc_root` variable in php.ini.

Edit.

Last possible problem with Apache or PHP is this line:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

It should be in httpd.conf. In `modules` directory there should be `libphp5.so` file, too.

IMHO if it's not one of these problem it's problem with WAMP, not Apache nor PHP. If so, sorry but I can't help you.

Comment: I have checked the doc_root in php.ini. it has no parameter. it is like "doc_root = "  what should i do?

Comment: It's directory where you put files. PHP won't parse files outside this directory.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't enabled .htaccess file and when you access the site then it doesn't redirect request to index.php. Rename .htaccess.sample to .htaccess and issue will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

are you open your website from http://localhost/ ?

if this is not your problem,it is php server definition problem.
reinstall wamp, it may be fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the page from your browser, e.g. `http://localhost/index.php`. Opening it in the browser from your filesystem just opens it as text.

Comment: i have opened the same way, it also saves the index file. Even all other files are not opened but saved by web browser.

Comment: @SAM Is your webserver running? And is your index.php in the htdocs-directory?

Comment: webserver is running. index.php is in home directory.

Comment: @SAM ok... so what exactly do you mean by 'it saves the file'? That the file is simply opened as text or does there a download-dialogue appear when calling the page? Can you call html-pages, e.g. `http://localhost/index.html`?

Comment: It shows download-dialogue box. Yes it shows html pages but not .php pages.

Comment: @SAM Weird... Now I can only guess: Check the /php/php.ini - is `engine = On`?