# WAMP Server - Asking to download index.php

Tags: php, html, wamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Site saves index.php file rather than opening it into localserver WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975639/site-saves-index-php-file-rather-than-opening-it-into-localserver-wamp)

I just installed WAMP on my computer. I moved a website into the www directory. When I go to the `index.php` of my website, I get a window that asks me to download the `index.php`.

The directory is: `c:/wamp/www/my website/index.php`

Can anyone tell me how to fix this, so that I could view the website instead of downloading it?

Thanks!

Comment: might be a problem with the header of your index.php

Comment: Maybe problem is .htaccess file. Remove .htaccess file on your site folder like c:/wamp/www/mywebsite/
I was same problem:)

Answer (score 3):

You have to enter your `index.php` file via domain like `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://localhost`, not via file patch like `c:\file.php`.

When you are running WAMP server on `xx` port `http://127.0.0.1:xx` is linked to WAMP's www folder like `c:/wamp/www/`. By default WAMP uses 80 port so you can visit just `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://localhost`

If you access your website by domain and it starts download anyway, please, check your `httpd.conf` file for `AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .php`.

---

And one more advice, do not use spaces while naming your website folders as

> Web servers have different ways of handling (encoding) the space
>   character. This is likely to cause problems when someone else is
>   linking to your website. They might encode the space character
>   incorrectly, resulting in a broken link.

Comment: Hey, I'm using http://localhost/mywebsite/ on the browser. Once I hit enter, a download window appears.

Comment: Seems like it was the .htaccess. Got rid of it and it's working now

Comment: @Kakenx your solution works for me. Just got ride of the .htaccess. Thanks a lot!